# Android http request library like Glide

Tags: android, httprequest, android-volley, android-glide

I tried to use Volley Android for http request and downloading zip files. I realize I have to implement everything from ground up, including the caching the file. Is there any library that have the following features:

1. Http request and get json response
2. Download file
3. Cache the file for a certain period of time, and exclude caching json.

I tried Glide and it seems to work with images only.

Comment: a quick google search : https://github.com/NYTimes/Store

Comment: try Retrofit...

Comment: @Supto, Retrofit seems great~ I dun nid to write codes, just annotation and config. Thanks for the answer